# Make swi prolog to return the predicate name

Tags: prolog

sorry i just want to return the predicate name america

```
america('kin').
novelist('kin').
writer(X):- novelist(X).
```

when i query swi below 
`writer(A),novelist(A)`

it just match
A = 'kin'
how to change the swi to make it return america?

Comment: Exactly why would you expect this to derive `'america'`? By querying all sorts of predicates until there is a "hit"?

Comment: This is exactly the same as doing `SELECT * FROM novelist, writer WHERE novelist.name = writer.name` and you expect the see the name of the table `america` to be output. That's not gonna work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does `america(X)` mean "X lives in America"? I'd suggest to make `america` an atom instead of a predicate, then define facts like:

```
lives_in(kin, america).
```

That allows you to define rules like:

```
novelist_living_in(X, Y) :- novelist(X), lives_in(X, Y).
```

so that you can do queries like:

```
novelist_living_in(kin, Y).
```